# SQL Server insert slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, performance

I have two servers where I installed SQL Server 2008

- Production: RAID 1 on SCSI disks
- Test: IDE disk

When I try to execute a script with about 35.000 inserts, on the test server I need 30 sec and instead on the production server more than 2 min!
Does anybody know why such difference? I mean, the DB are configured in the same way and the production server has also a RAID config, a better processor and memory...

THANKS!

Comment: Andrew, could you answer, what type of field has the primary key and what type of index has this field (CLUSTERED OR NONCLUSTERED).

Comment: The Primary key index is clustered on both servers

Comment: what type of field (PK field)? GUID?

Comment: Have you tested basic write performance on both machines, outside of SQL?  Perhaps the RAID 1 or the SCSI disks themselves are not as fast as you believe.

Comment: only INT and FLOAT data type...
The db is exactly the same since I exported it from production and imported in test server

Comment: "Have you tested basic write performance on both machines"
Which kind of test do you suggest?

Comment: Is it stable situation (so huge delay) or time to time? can I look at your script and table structure?

Comment: I would wonder if there were differences on the file growth chunk size also...(Autogrowth) under Files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that RAID 1 is for redundancy, and speed varies depending on the scenario. 35k inserts could cause a heavy random write overhead, slowing down performance.

How are you inserting these rows, are they wrapped in a SQL Transaction? If not already, then know that transactions cache queries and does batch disk updates, greatly increasing speed.

If it's via a SQL script file, wrap the inserts in BEGIN TRANSACTION / END TRANSACTION. For so many records [importing from file is probably better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

What are the indexes and padding on the server?  You may need to rebuild your indexes with more space in your pages and/or consider which indexes you really need.  If you want a quick test try `ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbname.dbo.tablename REORGANIZE.`

Also consider the usage on the production server.  In your test it's likely you (or very few) are the only person read/writing.  Get an idea for what else is going on in the db while you are doing this insert.

If both of those fail, run some monitoring on the production server and see if it's being slammed by other processes.

Comment: Took a simple insert of mine from 30 seconds to about 30 ms. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some other programs are running on the  production server that is consuming the resources like hard-disk and processor.

Also on the production server the time when you are executing the scripts at the same time operations are being performed on the DB and some queries are executing.

Answer (score 2):

There are three (high-level) issues to consider:

1. Activity on the server vs. available resources: it sounds like (judging from your responses) that this isn't an issue
2. Configuration of your indexes: again, it sounds like this isn't an issue if the development environment truly *is* identical in configuration (as it should be)
3. The volume of data vs. how thorough your indexes are

I think the third point might be your issue. Realize that the more (non-clustered) indexes you place on your table (and the more complex they are), the slower your data manipulation is going to be. Indexes are (in general) a tradeoff between query speed and modification speed. Obviously, this is a generalization and tuning is always required, but it's true in general.

Compare how much data is in the two environments; if the production environment has a substantial amount more (or if your table is highly indexed), then this could very well be your issue.

Comment: On the test server I imported the dump of the production DB, therefore the data and the index are the same..
Maybe something related the disks.. I'm using RAID1 on the production and I don't have RAID on the test server..

Comment: @andrew: Depending on your RAID controller, this could certainly be part of the issue. RAID1 (especially implemented in software) writes the same data to both drives.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to say.

First - yes, production may have more resources, but are they AVAILABLE? Or is production already running close to limit with the other stuff when you hit it? It is, after all, production.

This would be like my first idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...
The resources are available and there are no other users connected on the server.. Moreover, the index are configured in the same way as in the other test server...

Comment: I would still like to see a perfmon log first. Maybe some of your subsystems has issues - just because the disc is THEORETICALLY faster does not mean it really is. Crap happens. Been there, seen that. measure all important characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

If you also do selects on the database at the same time, make sure they are done with "with(nolock)"

Answer (score 0):

What is the volume of existing data in the two servers?

Time to INSERT will expand depending on the number of rows already in the table and the number of indexes.  If your test server table contains fewer rows pre-INSERT than the production server, the INSERT would be expected to execute more quickly there.